# How to install mysql-python in Windows?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm trying to run a django project in a Windows machine, but it keeps given me this error:

```
 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

The after some google search I found that the `mysql-python` library is necessary, for that I'm trying the command: `pip install mysql-python`, but keeps given me the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'fin
al',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0
.2\include" -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c _mysql.c -o build\temp.win
-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.o /Zl

gcc.exe: error: /Zl: No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm googling about it but no luck so far. Any idea how to solve this problem ?

--
**UPDATE**
@iwin, I tried to install what you recommend but this is what I received:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get mysql-python (mysqldb) work with anaconda (2/3) or python 2.7/3.4 or pip....
Solution see here http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/02/anaconda-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and eventually found the following solution.  The only thing that was different from our solutions was that I am using cygwin.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33i99j/does_anyone_know_how_to_install_mysqldb_with/

1. Go to your Anaconda Scripts directory (C:/Anaconda/Scripts)
2. In console type the following: `conda install mysql-python`